# Converting pinch to zoom to new InputSystem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert pinch to zoom from old input to new Input system using EnhancedTouch.Touch. Unfortunately I am clueless as to how to move forward from here? I am getting error as `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TouchPhase' and 'TouchPhase'`. How do I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch;
using Touch = UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch;

public class ZoomTouch : MonoBehaviour {
public Camera camera;
float touchDist = 0;
float lastDist = 0;

public void Update () {

if (Input.touchCount == 2) {
            Touch touch1 = Touch.activeFingers[0].currentTouch;
            Touch touch2 = Touch.activeFingers[0].currentTouch;

            if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Began && touch2.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                lastDist = Vector2.Distance (touch1.position, touch2.position);
            }

            if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && touch2.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                float newDist = Vector2.Distance (touch1.position, touch2.position);
                touchDist = lastDist - newDist;
                lastDist = newDist;

                camera.fieldOfView += touchDist * 0.1f;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code works. However, I did not have a touch device to test it. This simple code works, takes the distance between the present and the past, and zooms in on their delta.

```cs
public float lastDistance;
public float distance;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount < 2) return;

    var touch1 = Input.GetTouch(0);
    var touch2 = Input.GetTouch(1);
    
    distance = Vector2.Distance(touch1.position, touch1.position);

    if (Mathf.Abs(lastDistance-distance) >= 10) lastDistance = distance; // for avoiding sharp zooms on first touch
    
    Camera.main.fieldOfView += distance-lastDistance * 0.1f;

    lastDistance = distance;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but this is through old Input System. I am trying to implement in the new Input System.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using:

```
if (_activeTouch.phase == UnityEngine.InputSystem.TouchPhase.Began)
{
   _startPos = _activeTouch.screenPosition;
}
```

The problem is that if you simply write `TouchPhase`, it is using `enum UnityEngine.TouchPhase`, which is not the same as `enum UnityEngine.InputSystem.TouchPhase`.

You can also see that if you add `using UnityEngine.InputSystem;` the error changes to `TouchPhase' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.InputSystem.TouchPhase' and 'UnityEngine.TouchPhase`